# JQuery send element id data from ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm loading the page content without refresh using this code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //set trigger and container
            var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
                container = $('#container');
            //do on click
            trigger.on('click', function(e){
                /***********/
                 e.preventDefault();

                //get the link location that was clicked
                pageurl = $(this).attr('href');



                //to change the browser URL to th  if(pageurl!=window.location){
                  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl+'.php');



               /* reload content without refresh */
                //set loading img
                $('#container').append('<div id = "loading">WAIT...  <img src = "img/ajax-loader-small.gif" alt="Currently loading"   /></div>');
                //change img location to center
                $("#loading").css({"position": "absolute", "left": "50%", "top": "50%"});
                //get the  trigger to reload the contents
                var $this = $(this),
                    target = $this.data('target');

                container.load(target + '.php');



            });
        });
        // fix url in the browser when click on backward and foreword  arrows
        $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
            $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
                $('#container').html(data);
            }});
        });



    </script>
```

Then I'm trying to get the id value and send it to another page using ajax, since there's no refresh.

```
 <li><a href="#"><strong>CATEGORY</strong><span> MENU ELEMENTS</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a id="id_1"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_1</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_2"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_2</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_3"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_3</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_4"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_4</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_5"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_5</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_6"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_6</a></li>
                <li><a id="id_7"  data-target='post_category'>Sub_7</a></li>
            </ul>
   </li>
```

JQuery code

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click","a",function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: "post_category.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).attr("id")
        });
 });
</script>
```

php code in the other page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 echo 'Worked';
} else {
  echo 'No data';
}
```

the jquery take the id successfully, but  it didn't send the data to the required page correctly   so it always unset and I get No data  in the else condition. I tried everything, but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Try this: data{ id: $(this).attr("id") }

Comment: An alternative could be: data: "id="+$(this).attr("id")

Comment: Thank you ,but both codes didn't work

Comment: `$(this)` isn't what you might think it is. It's binded to the `ajax()` function and not the `on('click')`. This is a typical *lexical* scope (_that = this) issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be in the data you are trying to post.
You need to post a valid JSON object.

Make sure you construct a valid javascript object and then use the `JSON.stringify` function to convert your javascript object into a JSON object.

Set your id using `$(this)` outside of your `$.ajax` call to reference the anchor element instead of the `$.ajax` object.

Something like the following should give you the desired result:

```
<script>
    $('a').on("click", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "post_category.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: id
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still I get no data and else condition fire the error no data

Comment: See the updated answer, your $(this) is not referencing the anchor, but instead referencing the document which does not have an id set

Comment: In your code above, `$(this)` is actually binded to the `ajax()` method, and *not* the `on()` method (which is what you need). So `id: $(this).attr("id")` will be `undefined` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Need to send data in key-value pair, so that you can access them by key in the other page. 
Also this is referring to the document and thus $(this).attr('id') is null.
You can try the below code as shown:

```
<script>

$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
   var element =e.target;
    $.ajax({
        url: "post_category.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id':$(element).attr("id")}
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still I get no data and else condition fire the error no data

Comment: try adding a success callback in the ajax request. See if the request is successfully completing. @AhmadzIssa

Comment: I added   a success callback   and I get   "worked"  from the if statement, but in the page still getting no data!

Comment: where did put success callback. can you show in the code? Also I recommend trying the edited code.

Comment: <script>

    $(document).on("click","a",function(e){


        $.ajax({
            url: "post_category.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'id':$(this).attr("id")},
            success: function(data) {
               alert(data);

            }
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: The success  function didn't work in your edited code.

Comment: also  if I try to echo id  in the php page, I get error undefined vairable

Comment: if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 echo $_POST['id'];
} else {
  echo 'No data';
}    Please try this in your php code and show the alert. @AhmadzIssa,

Comment: So your data is being sent to the php page. You can access it there like this: $_POST['id']. Can you show how you accessed it earlier that caused the issue? @AhmadzIssa

Comment: That's the problem the data is being sent,but  it still says there's no data.Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\unv\post_category.php on line 5 No data.   Thie error after I tried to echo  $_POST['id'] !!!!!  can send you the whole project if you have time.  Thank you.

Comment: https://ia601501.us.archive.org/21/items/kingahmad_z_hotmail_Unv/unv.zip    or https://archive.org/details/kingahmad_z_hotmail_Unv     I added readme for the code location . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("click","a",function(e){   
     $.ajax({
        url: "post_category.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:$(this).attr("id")}
      });
  });
```

Try this you were missing id:(this).attr("id")